# Compare content of two lists, Java, Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist, compare

I'm creating simple grabber in Java for my use. Overall the thing I want to do is:

1. Get all links from main page and check if they are internal
2. Store internal link in a listOld (temporally they are stored in set to
   avoid duplicated links then saved to list)
3. Visit link from listOld
4. Get all links from page, again store them in set then in listNew
5. Go back to 3rd step, but visit next link from List (it's just a
   "for" loop on List that iterates trough every element on listOld)
6. When all links from List are visited compare listOld and listNew, every
   link listNew that's not on List is added to listTemp.
7. Links from listTemp and List are added to internalLinks
8. listOld and listNew are cleared, listTemp content is added to List
9. Go back to 3rd step
10. Program end when at then end of 6th step listTemp = null (so simple
     do...while with check, check changes to true when at the end of 6th
     step listTemp = null)

That's my code

```
package com.amazon.tests;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Grabber {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private List<String> internalLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Set<String> noDuplicates = new HashSet<>();
    private List<WebElement> linksOnPage = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> listOld = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> listNew = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> listTemp = new ArrayList<>();

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/TEST/LIB/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void teardown() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void grabber()
    {
        String hrefvalue = null;
        boolean check = false;


        driver.get("https://www.redbullmobile.pl/");
        linksOnPage = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));


        for (int i = 0; i<linksOnPage.size(); i++)
        {
            hrefvalue = linksOnPage.get(i).getAttribute("href");

            if(hrefvalue != null)
            {
                if(hrefvalue.contains("redbullmobile") && !hrefvalue.contains("facebook") && !hrefvalue.contains("redbullmobile.play.pl") && !hrefvalue.contains("redbullmobilecollect") && !hrefvalue.contains("fb.com") && !hrefvalue.contains(".pdf"))
                {
                    noDuplicates.add(linksOnPage.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
                }
            }
        }
        listOld.addAll(noDuplicates);
        hrefvalue = null;
        linksOnPage.clear();
        noDuplicates.clear();


    do 
    {
        listTemp.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i<listOld.size(); i++)
        {
            driver.get(listOld.get(i));
            linksOnPage = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            for (int i1 = 0; i1<linksOnPage.size(); i1++)
            {
                hrefvalue = linksOnPage.get(i1).getAttribute("href");
                if(hrefvalue != null)
                {
                    if(hrefvalue.contains("redbullmobile") && !hrefvalue.contains("facebook") && !hrefvalue.contains("redbullmobile.play.pl") && !hrefvalue.contains("redbullmobilecollect") && !hrefvalue.contains("fb.com") && !hrefvalue.contains(".pdf"))
                    {
                        noDuplicates.add(linksOnPage.get(i1).getAttribute("href"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //When all links from listOld are visited compare listOld and listNew, every link listNew that's not on List is added to listTemp.

        //Links from ListTemp and ListOld are added to ListFinal
        internalLinks.addAll(listOld);
        internalLinks.addAll(listTemp);
        //listOld and listNew are cleared, listTemp content is added to listOld
        listOld.clear();
        listNew.clear();
        listOld.addAll(listTemp);
        //Go back to 3rd step
        //Program end when at then end of 6th step listTemp = null (so simple do...while with check, check changes to true when at the end of 6th step listTemp = null)
        if (listTemp.isEmpty())
        {
            check = true;
        }
    }while(check);
    }
}
```

However I have a problem with Step 6. I don't really know how to compare every element on `listOld` with every element on `listNew` and then add elements without match to `listTemp`. Could someone help me?

Also I think I could shorten this code (basically get rid of code that is before start of (`do...while`) by just adding `https://www.redbullmobile.pl/` to `listOld` before start of `do...while`. Am I right or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, List contains an `addAll` method to add all elements of a list to the first one.

It also contains a [`removeAll` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) to do the opposite.

> **boolean removeAll(Collection c)**
>
> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection

Comment: So I can simply use `listNew.removeAll(listOld);` and then `listTemp.addAll(listNew);` ? Thanks a lot! For some reason I thought it will need much more work than this.